# Messing around with OOP in Python

Tags: python, function, class, oop

I'm playing around with OOP in Python and I am trying to figure out some stuff related to inheritance. . I have some code here that has a few classes. A class called Blacksmith which behaves as expected and a class called Hero which I am trying to call a function from but I recieve an unexpected output.

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.health=100
        self.name = name
    #   self.player = player
    def printName(self):
        print self.name
    #def printPlayerName(self):
    #   print self.player

class Blacksmith(Character):
    def __init__(self,name, forgeName):
        super(Blacksmith, self).__init__(name)
        #self.name = "Billy"
        self.forge = Forge(forgeName)

class Hero(Character):
    playerName = "Player"
    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Hero, self).__init__(name)
    def setplayername(self,inputplayername):
        playerName = inputplayername

class Forge:
    def __init__(self,forgeName):
        self.name = forgeName

bs = Blacksmith("Billy", "Billy's Forge")
print bs.health
bs.printName()
print bs.forge.name
player1 = Hero("Methos")
print player1.name
player1.setplayername("Chris")
#print playher1.playerName
print player1.playerName
```

Output is:

```
raina@DESKTOP-291MTC0 ~/python
$ python learningoopclasses01.py
100
Billy
Billy's Forge
Methos
Player
```

Can anyone explain why this output says "Player" and not "Chris". Another question I have is I am not entirely sure how the **init** methods work. What does super do in these cases? What does calling init with a name value do exactly? Thanks.

Comment: Turns out the issue was actually fixed by changing this line: playerName = inputplayername to self.playerName = inputplayername. My other questions still stand, however.

Comment: What's the other question? Please [edit] your question to update it before someone spends time on solving a problem which is already gone.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is called when an object of that Class is created. With this method, we will also use the `self` variable to represent the instance of the object itself. It has to be explicitly declared in Python to be defined on an object.

For example,

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self, score1, score2, score3):
        self.scores = [score1, score2, score3]
```

If you want to assign scores to Student 1, you would only need to use because `stu_1` already has `score` as an attribute in it:

```
stu_1 = Student(80, 90, 85)
```

In addition, `__init__` also will notify you if any parameters are entered incorrectly according to what it has been set up.

`super()` is used to first call the parent(super) class of `Blacksmith`, which is `Character`, and allows you access `Character`'s property.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `super()` in Blacksmith's `__init__` method is equal to its superclass, which in this case is Character.

You could also replace `super(Blacksmith, self).__init__(name)` with `Character.__init__(self, name)`. The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

A slight adjustment to

```
def setplayername(self,inputplayername):
    self.playerName = inputplayername
```

In the `Hero` class will fix it, if you don't want to change anything else.